# Eventual Career Objective

Tags: education

I am a Front-End Developer with several years of experience as well as I have my B.S. in Computer Science. I am doing research and pursuing my MS in Computer Science. However, I am somewhat struggling to word my career objective correctly and in a fashion in which I could be considered for admittance into Grad School. How could this snippet be modified to accomplish the goal while remaining under 150 characters:

> I have always been fascinated with disassembling and reassembling objects to figure out how they work. When I was ten, my mother brought home several desktop computers. I figured out how to remove all of the components and combine or reinstall them, all while keeping the computers in an operable state. This was the beginning of a constantly growing interest with computers and how they operate. My interests range from hardware to operating systems, and current employment in software engineering.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for academia.se.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's about writing motivation letters. [It has been reposted on Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62616/eventual-career-objective).